# Sharepoint List Item Field Visibility

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I have a sharepoint list in which I have certain columns which I want to hide from certain users, how to configure or to do that in wss 3.0.

Let me know

Thanks
RHM

Comment: have u check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9478293/hide-show-fields-to-user-based-on-a-group-permission-in-sharepoint-2010 may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

There is a codeplex project for column level permissions located here: http://www.codeplex.com/SPListDisplaySetting .

Hope this is helpful for you.

Comment: doesnt sharepoint wss have any out of the box feature for it?

Comment: out of the box like this feature is not available.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on whether you mean in views or in forms. In views, you simply don't show the columns. For forms, you can customize them in SharePoint Designer to show different columns based on permissions or any other criteria you define.